# Creating Dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have just started working on Javascript, and I got really stuck on my task. I hope people here would help me understand.
There is already a dropdown  created using HTML, but there is no data. I need to populate that dropdown with bunch of IDs that are retrieved from Table. Lets say the table name is  `TABLE_NAME` and that hold IDs. To get that id in Javascript, I can do something like

```
var idTable= getId("TABLE_NAME");  //or not sure
```

here `idTable` already have list object.

The question is how can I approach from here?

```
    function DropBox(dropdown){
    var ht="<tr>";
    ht=ht+"<td class='formInput'>";
    ht=ht+"<option value='-1'>select</option>";
    if(dropdown.vt.length>0){
    var idTable=getId("TABLE_NAME");
    for(var i=0;i<idTable.length; i++){
    var value= idTable[i];
    ht=ht+"<option value'"+value[i]+"'>"+value[i]+"</option>";
    }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need to find yourself an introduction to JavaScript.

Comment: What is `TABLE_NAME` a database (SQL) table?

Comment: Show the code (HTML and Javascript) that you have so far.

Comment: @Halcyon, definitely, please let me know if there is any good text book that you know i should follow, easy to understand

Comment: @acdcjunior: it is DB2

Comment: @Patrick Q
  function DropBox(dropdown){
  var ht="<tr>";
  ht=ht+"<td class='formInput'>";
  ht=ht+"<option value='-1'>select</option>";
  if(dropdown.vt.length>0){
  var idTable=getId("TABLE_NAME");
  for(var i=0;i<idTable.length; i++){
  ht=ht+"<option value'"+value[i]+"'>"+value[i]+"</option>";
  }

  }
 }
vt is membervariable from java that holds the information

Comment: Put your code in the question (by editing the question), not in the comments.

Comment: @David, JavaScript runs on the client side. The server that serves the page is the one that must access the database. For that, it must run a server-side language, such as PHP, ASP, JSP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've not provided any context for me to add this code too, I'll give you a generic example of using Javascript to populate a drop down. In HTML, a drop down is a `select` element, and the children of that `select` element are `option` elements.

**Example**

**HTML**

```
<select id="dropdown">
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");

option.text = "Test";

dropdown.add(option);
```

This will create a new `option` element, and append it onto the `dropdown` object, which represents the `select` element.

**For Reference..**

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sHW4/) that showcases this functionality for you.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I don't want to populate from hard coded value, rather i want to populate for the retrieved data. I have edited my question with the snippet of my code, please let me know your thoughts